# 301 redirect subdirectory and anything in it

Tags: .htaccess

I bought an old site that apparently used some kind of a CMS, maybe wordpress. 
Now it's a simple html site. I want to redirect www.example.com/main and everything in that directory to root. In other words, if a url is example.com/main/a_bunch_of_garbage that should 301 redirect to the homepage. Here is what I have but it doesn't quite work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/main/(.*)$ http://www.example.com
```

If the url doesn't contain any weird characters like ? or = then it works. But for example, if I go to www.example.com/main/index.php?option=com_content&view=post&id=84&Itemid=982/
Then although it does redirect to the homepage, in the address bar, I still see the entire URL. Can I fix this? 
I also just remembered another problem I had. If I put example.com/main (without forward slash after main) the redirect doesn't work. It only works if I put example.com/main/ (with forward slash)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mod_rewrite` rules only and avoid mixing `RedirectMatch` here. Have your rules like this in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^main(/.*)$ $1? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`?` in the end is used to strip off any existing query string.